# Prevent Facemash cheating through url

Tags: php, url

I've been using the Facemash-like script. But the problem is that while rating people when we actually point our cursor towards a picture for every image there is a URL like:

```
rate.php?winner=XXX&loser=XXXX1
```

So, if we directly type this in the address bar the trick works! Hence there is chance for users to hack for their scores. I know we can change the GET methods to POST methods. And I've searched for this and nothing really helped me out. The links to the files(rate.php and index.php) are also included in the comments of this question.

Comment: Two words:  input validation.  Even using POST instead of GET, it can still easily be hacked.  You need to keep track on the server side that an IP address has already voted for a pair of images.

Comment: Can you hyperlink to 'the facemash-like script', and/or briefly explain _in your question_ what that is? My guess is that a number of readers won't know.

Comment: Thanx! And I knew about the IP tracking thing.

Comment: And the files are included in here [rate.php](http://jsfiddle.net/6xLR6/) [index.php](http://jsfiddle.net/AvF4M/1/)

Comment: Read [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), adapt to it, your scripts are vulnerable

Comment: thanks! But would be helpful if you tell me what changes i can make in the code! I'm already working on it.. but no success! The site is Live and some users already knew about this hack! So would be helpful if helped me with the posted code!

Answer (score 2):

I'm making my own Facemash-like engine and here's what I do.

I store two challengers' `id`s in PHP `$_SESSION`. Before displaying the new pair I check if `$_SESSION` is set and if it is I just display them instead of taking new pair from a database. This prevents cheating by refreshing the page until you get your photo. I did it because the community I'm making facemash for is relatively small.

So links look like `vote.php?v=left` or `right`. In `vote.php` I get `id`s from a `$_SESSION['right']` and `$_SESSION['left']` and then unset them. I looking forward to publish my script some day.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you change from GET to POST then the parameters will not be displayed in the URL upon submission.

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_post.asp

Comment: As Ed said after you, this is insufficient to prevent duplicate voting. You need to keep track of IP addresses, so long as you're prepared to block several legitimate users behind a firewall. Alternatively, get people to register with an email address, and require their being authenticated before they can vote.

Comment: Thanks candor! I know the difference between the GET and POST methods. Anyways i request you to have a look at the two files attached and suggest me the TODO changes to prevent the hack!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of relying on GET/POST to determine the comparison, store the data in `$_SESSION` instead, and only let the user pick 'image1' or 'image2', then invalidate and create a new comparison after a choice is made.

[Example site - form only lets you choose 1 or 2](http://robus.info/facemash/)

Comment: can you please tel me how to do that! I'v been trying that but no success! :(