# Looped javascript attacks from browser console?

Tags: javascript, ajax, console

I'm developing a Facemash-like rating system. Recently I decided to switch from simple voting links (`href=vote.php?v=left` or `right` while `id`'s [were stored in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10932504/prevent-facemash-cheating-through-url/13873444#13873444) `$_SESSION`) to AJAX. Then I realised that it's extremely vurnelable. In a browser console cheater can invoke an infinite loop that checks picture url then, if it matches some specified url, votes for it, and if it doesn't match, votes for just `left` or `right`. Is there any way to prevent this besides obviously not implementing ajax voting at all? Maybe there is some command to break the loop in console or something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is just a specific example of a general principle: *You can't trust anything sent to the server from the client*. You must implement checks at the server end to rate-limit (or just limit), validate, etc., because people can send you any information they like (they don't even have to be using a web browser to do it).

In this case, if you're letting people vote on things, you have to limit how many times an individual can vote on a specific item (and probably rate-limit how often they can vote, period).

Comment: I agree. Always write code server side to ensure things like this don't happen. Can never just accept client-side data as foolproof or cheat proof.

Comment: Maybe a little edit on how the OP could prevent this with some server side checking. Perhaps having a Guid or unique identifier client-side that is passed server side, and then marked as having voted for said link so that they cannot vote for it again. Same way you can't upvote for the same question/answer on stackoverflow.com twice

Comment: Okay, I accept this as answer then.
I will just force user to enter captcha when votes limit exceeds.